# Texstudio + custom cwl: #include command ignored

Tags: texstudio, editors, auto-completion, syntax-highlighting

**Goal** I am trying to derive my own class from `memoir` and would like to include all the auto-completiong from the original `memoir` class.

**Problem** I wrote a customg `.cwl` file using `#include:class-memoir`. But that seems to be ignored as the corresponding commands are not recognized in TexStudio. *Is there something wrong with the `.cwl`?*

**Setting** I am using TexStudio 2.11.2 on an Ubuntu 16.04 with pdflatex. I've put the `.cwl` file in `$HOME/.config/texstudio/completion/user` and loaded it in TexStudio explicitly in `Options->Configure Texstudio->Completion`. I am sure that my `.cwl` is loaded because I added a test command which is recognized.

**MWE**

*test-derived.tex*

```
\documentclass{derived-from-memoir}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Title page definitions
\begin{titlingpage}
\title{This is an Awesome Title}
\author{Awesome Name}
\date{\today}
\aliaspagestyle{titlingpage}{plain}
\setlength\droptitle{30pt} % vertical position of the title
\end{titlingpage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\maketitle

\cleartorecto

My awesome text! \testcmd{And the test works!}

\end{document}
```

*derived-from-memoir.cls*

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{derived-from-memoir}[2017/05/12 derived-from-memoir class]

\ProcessOptions\relax 

\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,onecolumn,openright
%,final
,draft
,fleqn % displayed math environments will be indented an amount \mathindent from the left margin (the default is to center the environments).
,openbib %each part of a bibliography entry will start on a new line, with second and succeding lines indented by \bibindent (the default is for an entry to run continuously with no indentations).
]{memoir}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\let\testcmd\emph

\endinput
```

*class-derived-from-memoir.cwl*

```
#include:class-memoir.cwl

\testcmd{asubd}
```

After loading *class-derived-from-memoir.cwl*, the part `\testcmd{And the test works!}` is recognized, but not the `memoir` commands, i.e. `\droptitle`, `titlingpage`, `\aliaspagestyle` and `\cleartorecto`.

Comment: Check maybe `completion/autogenerated` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your class-derived-from-memoir.cwl file should be

```
#include:memoir

\testcmd{asubd}
```

Comment: You should replace `#include:memoir` with `#include:class-memoir`